# Why does hard drive with only two day lifetime usage has so many start/stop counts?

Tags: hard-drive

I wonder how it is possible or why this happens why hard drives show such a big number of start/stop counts while the hard drive has only 1-2 days of lifetime usage.

What makes the hard drive to start/stop so much?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely sleep settings.

Comment: What tool are you using to measure? My 8 year old Thinkpad X230 shows 29,500 on hours (1,230 days or 3.4 contiguous years). Start Stop count is 4,000. Given the above, the count may have rolled over once or twice.

Comment: the software is called "Hard Disk Sentinel"